# identical lines shown as different in post revision diff

Tags: bug, status-norepro

If you go to https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/115012/revisions and select the *side-by-side markdown* format, you see something like:

[image: screenshot]

See how those 3 highlighted lines in the middle are actually identical. I did copy-paste the source of both into files and run diff on them and saw no difference.

Comment: When I fetch the source of the original post, I see special characters which are not present in the source of Edit #3. In browser (both Chromium and Chrome) they display as boxes. Copy & pasting the original source into Sublime (graphical text editor) yields <0x1b>. `curl`-ing the source and performing a `hexdump`, the extra characters again appear as 1b. These don't display in your side-by-side markdown, but they do display in mine (as boxes). Finally, my side-by-side markdown contains more differences than yours (there is at least one 'box' character on each line in the pasted codeblocks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Kevin said, there are escape (0x1b) bytes in there that seem to not be rendering on your machine. They show up as arrows on mine:

[image]

Comment: OK, my bad, I see them now when I _edit_ the old revision. I missed them earlier as they were removed when pasting before doing the diff.

Comment: At this point, should I remove the "bug" tag, or delete the  question?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas - I'd delete the question.

Answer (score 1):

I see the same diff output as you but what’s even odder is that I didn’t consciously modify the question body when I made that edit. However, from viewing the source (before and after), I can clearly see that all the Escape characters were removed by the edit.

It’s likely that I used the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key to pass through the *body* textarea as I navigated from the *title* input field to the *tags* input field but I didn’t stop to change anything (if I did, it would have been to remove the single trailing whitespace). At the time, I was running Firefox 60 on Windows 7 without any unusual extensions – though I’ve only recently installed Tridactyl to try it out.

Comment: I did believe that SE was stripping control characters anyway as that can be abused (when copy-pasting into terminals that unlike mine don't strip them, see [How can I protect myself from this kind of clipboard abuse?](//security.stackexchange.com/q/39118)). Maybe  they only started doing it recently (and that article was old before you started editing it).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas  Of course. I should have remembered that from posting [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/355620/22812) to [Is Vim immune to copy-paste attack?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/355610/22812) just over a year ago. It's great that SE strip out the control characters from posts.